# Collecting network information

Tags: networking, sed, awk, regular-expression

I need to collect information about the network usage of each process.

Nethogs presents the data I need in real time, I am trying to save the output to a file in order parse it and plot the data.

[image: nethogs output]

The white bar is messing the output, so I used:

```
sudo nethogs wlan0 | perl -pe 's/\x1b.*?[mGKH]//g'
```

[image]

Now it is better, but the DEV and SENT column are merged. 
One more thing, I need to add a timestamp per flush.

Answer (score 1):

After hitting with my head against the walls during three days, I decided to change the source code of nethogs in order to print the way I need.

If  someone needs:
https://github.com/hdlopesrocha/nethogs

The result is something like this:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.2-SNAPSHOT
TIME PID USER PROGRAM DEV SENT RECEIVED
Ethernet link detected
Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)
2016-02-11.00:38:29    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.026       0.026KB/sec
2016-02-11.00:38:30    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.026       0.026KB/sec
2016-02-11.00:38:31    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.026       0.026KB/sec
2016-02-11.00:38:32    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.026       0.026KB/sec
2016-02-11.00:38:33    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.026       0.026KB/sec
2016-02-11.00:38:34    3218 hdlopesrocha    /usr/lib/firefox/firefox    wlan0        0.036       0.038KB/sec
```

Be aware that this will override the original nethogs

Feel free to contact me if you need a different format.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor wlan0

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

You can monitor network bandwidth of both eth0 and eth1 interfaces

```
nethogs [option] eth0 eth1
```

**options** :

-d     delay for refresh rate.

For example, to set 5 seconds as your refresh rate, then type the command as.

```
 sudo nethogs -d 5
```

-h     display available commands usage.

-p     sniff in promiscious mode (not recommended).

-t     tracemode.

-V     prints Version info.

Keyboard shortcuts

Use the following interactive controls:

m : Cycle between display modes (kb/s, kb, b, mb)

r : Sort by received.

s : Sort by sent.

q : Quit and return to the shell prompt.